# I would like to unload kernel modules that show as busy

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, kernel-modules

I want to unload the modules "gsch and redirfs" from kernel on RHEL 7.2 , which is causing frequent kernel panic.

But when I try to unload , I am getting below error.

```
# modprobe -r gsch
modprobe: FATAL: Module gsch is in use.

# modprobe -r redirfs
modprobe: FATAL: Module redirfs is in use.

# lsmod | grep gsch
gsch                   88591  4
redirfs                79430  1 gsch
```

As checked , no processes holding these modules,

```
# ps -ef | grep gsch
root     26417  7838  0 10:58 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto gsch
# lsof | grep gsch
#
```

Comment: Your modules are being used. The third column in `lsmod` is the number of processes using the modules. You will not see modules as processes in `ps -ef` or as files in `lsof` because modules are compiled kernel code, and not files or processes by themselves. The module code gets loaded into memory when needed by a process, and you need to know what the module does to identify which process might have loaded it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029526/how-to-find-the-list-of-processes-using-a-particular-kernel-module and the question linked in it for further help. `dmesg` is probably your best bet at figuring out what caused the module to load.

Comment: As per the given link , I have checked dmesg command and found that service systemd-logind is holding the gsch module.

But I couldn't stop the service becoz whenever I stop its again starting automatically. kindly advise.

Comment: You can't stop systemd-logind because that services manages the user logins of your system. You'll break the entire system if you try to disable that. A quick google search shows that `gsch` and `redirfs` modules are RHEL proprietary modules and to get info about them you need a RHEL subscription. If you have a subscription, the best approach would be to contact RHEL support for this issue. If not, you should wait for someone here who knows about RHEL to answer here.

Comment: Munir - But as checked with Red-hat , they are saying these modules are third party module and they will not take any responsibility for this... Lets see anyone coming for this...

Answer (score 1):

These modules are for real-time file access of the Antivirus software. Judging from the name "Trend Deep Security Agent" Trend Micro Antivirus, but it could another.

Answer (score 0):

These are modules from Trend Deep Security Agent:

```
# locate gsch
/opt/ds_agent/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/gsch.ko
/opt/ds_agent/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/gsch.ko.version
/opt/ds_agent/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64/gsch.ko
/opt/ds_agent/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64/gsch.ko.version

# locate redirfs
/opt/ds_agent/2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64/redirfs.ko
/opt/ds_agent/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64/redirfs.ko
```

Comment: That is, the ds_agent needs to be stopped first before unloading the modules, yes?